# Cassandra for P2P distributed network

Tags: cassandra, p2p

Client asks to create data storage for P2P distributed network but doesn't want to create dedicated nodes/servers for database service - all nodes should be equal. Or at least subset of nodes should run database system. I consider Cassandra as candidate because it has no "master" server - Cassandra instances in cluster have equal responsibility. Network consists from 50 nodes. There is no neither intensive data writes/reads to storage (one DB access per minute) nor significant volumes of data. No real-time requirement. Nodes are geographically distributed.
Is it good idea to run Cassandra instance on each node in this P2P network so that all nodes will be really peer to peer - equal?

Comment: What sort of data volumes are you expecting to store?  More clarify about your requirements (availability, schema, etc) would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Someone asked this question previously but I can't recall if it was on ASF Slack #cassandra channel or the Cassandra mailing list.

The quick answer is yes, it is a good choice. In the other P2P use case, each peer would store all data for that peer alone in a single-node instance with RF=1. But they had dozens of peers distributed across geographies.

On face value, it seemed dangerous that they had dozens of single-node clusters since there were no replicas so if a Cassandra node went down, the peer would effectively be offline. However they explained that since they had dozens of peers scattered all over the globe, their system can tolerate the peer outage since it will just contact the nearest peer in the network.

So again, it was a good use case because they needed Cassandra's fast writes and millisecond-latency for reads. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for answer. In this p2p network peers should be able to read data written by other peer - data is not local for peer, so I thought that all peers should be part of the same cluster where data is replicated and if peer is offline then data stored in its DB instance is still available from other peers.

Comment: Yes, I agree. :) I was simply using the other use case as an example of what they chose to do and why. Their use case was unique and not the norm. Cheers!